# Which -newerXY option finds all files that are accessed after creating or modifying another file?

Tags: bash, find

This question relates to Xubuntu 22.04 if that matters. Probably it is a general Unix question, however.

In a shell script, I first want to create a reference file, e.g. by

```
echo $(date) > ~/reference.file
```

Then I want to start some application up to a certain step in its workflow. I want to know, **which files were accessed by the application up to this point**.

Then I want to continue the first mentioned shell script (or another one) using `find` to show me all files which have been accessed or modified. Of course I want to leave out all occurrences from `/sys` or `/proc`, because there could be an incredible number of them. I have tried out something like

```
  find ${WO} -type d \( -path /sys -o -path /proc \) \
  -prune -o -name '*' \
  -newerac ~/reference.file \
  -type f \
  -printf "%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TT %p\n" 2>/dev/null | \
  sort -r | \
  ssed -R 's/^([^.]+)\.\d+ (.*)$/\1 \2/'
```

and I tested it by issuing the commands

```
cat /tmp/test
echo $(date) > /tmp/test2
```

and then the `find` command mentioned above. Among other files from parallel processes it only found `/tmp/test2` (the one which was modified by the second command), but it did not find `/tmp/test`, which only was listed by the `cat` command. To my understanding, listing is an access and should be caught by `-newerac ~/reference.file`.

**What should I change in my find command?**

The answer of a question from the comments:

```
$ mount | grep "$(df ~/reference.file | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')"
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime)
$
```

Of course, because it is on a SSD, in `/etc/fstab` there is

`defaults,noatime` in the line for `/home` and

`errors=remount-ro,noatime` in the line for `/`.

I was surprised that `find` with option `-atime -0,01` lists files and timestamps from the last quarter of an hour or so. From were is this atime-information? Is it kept only in RAM and no longer available after rebooting?

Comment: What is the OS and the filesystem and the mount options (and the care or disregard that SSD can wear off etc.) ? Example: Linux often defaults to "relatime" meaning access time won't be reliable. but tmpfs often used for /tmp on Linux doesn't default to relatime.

Comment: What is the output of `mount | grep "$(df ~/reference.file | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')"` ?

Comment: Instead of `echo $(date) > ~/reference.file` why not just `date > ~/reference.file`?

Answer (score 0):

From the find man page, [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> `-anewer reference`
>
>   Time of the last access of the current file is more recent than
>   that of the last data modification of the
>   *reference*
>   file.

Answer (score 0):

The comment asking for the mounting options of the drive is justified: My mass storage is an SSD and in order not to wear it out prematurely with atime writes, it was mounted with `defaults,noatime`. **But then no `atime` is registered at all**. One can easily check it like this:

```
a@W:~$ touch reference.file
a@W:~$ rm -f test
a@W:~$ echo $(date) > test
a@W:~$ mount | grep "$(df test | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')"
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime)
a@W:~$ LC_ALL=C stat test # all 4 timestamps will be equal...
  File: test
  Size: 26          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 6033466     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/adalbert)   Gid: ( 1002/  aoderv)
Access: 2024-02-27 09:16:54.677820647 +0100
Modify: 2024-02-27 09:16:54.677820647 +0100
Change: 2024-02-27 09:16:54.677820647 +0100
 Birth: 2024-02-27 09:16:54.677820647 +0100
a@W:~$ date; cat test                        # reading access
2024-02-27T09:18:04+01:00
2024-02-27T09:16:54+01:00
a@W:~$ LC_ALL=C stat test
  File: test
  Size: 26          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 6033466     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/adalbert)   Gid: ( 1002/  aoderv)
Access: 2024-02-27 09:16:54.677820647 +0100  # <=== NOT changed! ===
Modify: 2024-02-27 09:16:54.677820647 +0100
Change: 2024-02-27 09:16:54.677820647 +0100
 Birth: 2024-02-27 09:16:54.677820647 +0100
a@W:~$ # find with -neweram reference.file will NOT see the access.
```

This shows that the read access is not registered. Then you have no chance at all to determine when the file was accessed using find even with the correct options of it.

Then I changed the mount option in `/etc/fstab/` to

```
UUID=12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789012  /home  ext4  rw,nodiratime,lazytime,strictatime  0  2
```

This is the outcome of the above experiments after reboot:

```
a@W:~$ rm test
a@W:~$ echo $(date) > test
a@W:~$ mount | grep "$(df test | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')"
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw,nodiratime,lazytime)
a@W:~$ LC_ALL=C stat test # all 4 timestamps will be equal...
  File: test
  Size: 26          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 6033466     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/adalbert)   Gid: ( 1002/  aoderv)
Access: 2024-02-26 23:26:25.102982504 +0100
Modify: 2024-02-26 23:26:25.102982504 +0100
Change: 2024-02-26 23:26:25.102982504 +0100
 Birth: 2024-02-26 23:26:25.102982504 +0100
a@W:~$ cat test            # reading access
2024-02-26T23:26:25+01:00
a@W:~$ LC_ALL=C stat test  # access time will be later than the other timestamps
  File: test
  Size: 26          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 6033466     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/adalbert)   Gid: ( 1002/  aoderv)
Access: 2024-02-26 23:28:46.307180653 +0100   # <=== this is later than the other timestamps below ===
Modify: 2024-02-26 23:26:25.102982504 +0100
Change: 2024-02-26 23:26:25.102982504 +0100
 Birth: 2024-02-26 23:26:25.102982504 +0100
a@W:~$ # under these circumstances, find with -neweram reference.file will see the access.
a@W:~$ # Use option -printf "%AY-%Am-%AdT%AT %p\n" to show the access time.
```

A script to display all last access or modification timestamps might look like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # ************************ 00_access.sh *************************
 # List which files have been accessed since the last call of the
 # script (=timestamp of ${REFERENCE}) have been read or changed
 # (without files in /proc and in /sys).
 #
 # After a copy operation, all four times for the copy are
 # are the same, including the atime. This is also the case for
 # newly created files. For this reason, copied and newly created
 # files are displayed here are displayed as read-only files.
 # The atime of the source file during a copy operation is really
 # the access access time of the copy-read operation.
 #
 # Call e.g:
 #   <path to wherer it is stored>/00_access.sh /
 #
 # The parameter, here /, can also be omitted. Then the
 # applies from the current position in the directory tree.
 #
 # You can also assign this to a key (e.g. to Super-Z):
 #
 #  bash -c "<path to wherer it is stored>/00_access.sh / >> \
 #    /home/$(whoami)/atime.txt;                             \
 #    if [[ -e /home/$(whoami)/refernce.file ]] ;            \
 #    then exit ;                                            \
 #    else mousepad /home/$(whoami)/atime.txt;               \
 #    fi"
 # ***************************************************************
 RED="\033[1;31m"
 BLUE="\033[1;34m"
 GREEN="\033[1;32m"
 YELLOW="\033[1;33m"
 MAGENTA="\033[1;35m"
 NONE="\033[0m"
 REFERENCE=/home/$(whoami)/reference.file   # this file exists between first and second call
 if [[ -e ${REFERENCE} ]]
 then                                       # ${REFERENCE} present indicates second call
   notify-send "2. call of 00_access.sh"
   cat ${REFERENCE}
   echo "=== Read accesses or newly created (i.e. all four times the same):"
   WO=$1                                    # variable was used during development
   find ${WO} -type d \( -path /sys -o -path /proc \) \
    -prune -o -name '*'                               \
    -neweram ${REFERENCE}                             \
    -type f                                           \
    -printf "%AY-%Am-%AdT%AT %p\n" 2>/dev/null |      \
    grep -v 00_access.sh |                            \
    grep -v ${REFERENCE} |                            \
    sort |                                            \
    ssed -R 's/^([^.]+)\.\d+ (.*)$/\1 \2/'
 
   echo "=== modified:"
   find ${WO} -type d \( -path /sys -o -path /proc \) \
    -prune -o -name '*'                               \
    -newermm ${REFERENCE}                             \
    -type f                                           \
    -printf "%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TT %p\n" 2>/dev/null |      \
    grep -v 00_access.sh |                            \
    grep -v ${REFERENCE} |                            \
    grep -v /home/$(whoami)/atime.txt |               \
    sort  |                                           \
    ssed -R 's/^([^.]+)\.\d+ (.*)$/\1 \2/'
 
   echo -e "=== End:  $(\date -Iseconds)  00_access.sh finished.  ==="
   rm ${REFERENCE}   # the next call to the script will count as the first one again
   notify-send "2. call to 00_access.sh finished."
   echo                                     # put an empty line below the output
 
 else                                       # ${REFERENCE} present indicates second call
   notify-send "1. call to 00_access.sh: take note of timestamp."
 
   # Check if atime is recorded in the calling context...
   touch ${REFERENCE}
   MOUNT=$(mount | grep "$(df ${REFERENCE} | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')")
   if [[ ! "$(echo ${MOUNT} | grep nodiratime | grep lazytime)" ]]
   then                                     # without atime at ${REFERENCE} ?
     echo -e "mounted as: ${MOUNT}\n${RED}read access can't be shown!${NONE}"
     echo -e "This script will note only new created or modified files there."
   fi                                       # without atime at ${REFERENCE} ?
 
   if [[ $1 ]]
   then                                     # was it called with a parameter?
       zusätzlich prüfen, ob atime für $1 vom System mitgeschrieben wird...
     MOUNT=$(mount | grep "$(df $1 | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')")
     if [[ ! "$(echo ${MOUNT} | grep nodiratime | grep lazytime)" ]]
     then                                   # without atime at $1 ?
       echo -e "$1 is mountet as: ${MOUNT}\n${RED}atime is not rcorded there!${NONE}"
       echo -e "This script will note only new created or modified files there."
     fi                                     # without atime at $1 ?
     echo -e "=== Begin:  $(\date -Iseconds)  00_access.sh mit »$1« ===" > ${REFERENCE}
   else                                     # was it called with a parameter?
     echo -e "=== Begin:  $(\date -Iseconds)  00_access.sh ohne Argument ===" > ${REFERENCE}
   fi                                       # was it called with a parameter?
 fi                                         # ${REFERENCE} present indicates second call
```

On the first invocation, it just records the start time in `reference.file`. On the second invocation, it uses `find` to find the files which have been accessed after the `mtime` of `reference.file` and the files which have been modified after the `mtime` of `reference.file`. After outputting its results, it removes `reference.file` such that the next invocation of the script will be the start moment.

Advantageously one might associate it with a keyboard shortcut (e.g. Super-Z) as described in the documentation inside of the script. This way it will accumulate such file access notes between the starting and the terminating invocation and show them in the editor after each second invocation by the shortcut . Enjoy!